# How to configure elasticsearch write log

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to config elasticsearch write (post/put) log, all the write operations must be logged, but read can be ignored. Can anyone tell ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/logging.html

Comment: I had read this doc before, but can not find the way to log only the write operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Logstash and/or Elastic Watcher plugin.